# WCF routing using XPath : invalid qualified name exception

Tags: wcf, xpath, wcf-routing

I am trying to impelemnt content based routing using XPath in wcf.

I have create class library which contains service contract and data contract as following.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://orders/")]
public interface IService5
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

[DataContract]
public class Quantity
{
    [DataMember]
    public int value1 { get; set; }

}
```

I created one service as follows:

```
public class Service5 : IService5
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered in service 5: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

And I am trying to implement routing based on 'value'

In app.config (inside router project) i hav added following lines for namespace and XPath filter

```
<namespaceTable>
  <add prefix="cc" namespace="http:orders/Quantity/"/>
</namespaceTable>
<filters>
  <filter name="All" filterType="XPath" filterData="cc://value1 &gt; 500 " />
```

But whenever i run the code i get an exception for ' cc://value1 > 500 ' as invalid qualified name exception.

How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are **multiple** things wrong here:

1. The class `Quantity` on which you appear to want to apply the filter does not feature in your service contract at all, so will be entirely absent in the XML for filtering purposes.
2. The namespace in your router config starts `http:orders`, when the service contract namespace starts `http://orders`.
3. The namespace in your router config contains `/Quantity`, when the service contract namespace does not.
4. The filter xpath *cc://value1* is not a valid xpath
5. ---

Comment: Really thanks for such quick reply , and really sorry for those silly mistakes. As u mentioned in 2 nd point i am using http://orders in sted of  http:orders and remove Quantity from namespace too. Still the reeor is there. And i also unable to understand your first and fourth point . can u explain it in brief Please.      Pushkar

Comment: The main problem is that you appear to be filtering on a message property which will not exist in the request you want to route based on it. All the other problems are just coding issues. This one is a design problem. You need to put the Quantity type into your request before you can route by this value.

Comment: Ya actually i thought it might be the problem with serialization thats why i put it in Property. Actually in my original case I dont have Quantity as data contract. I was using 'value' (which is a parameter for function) directly in XPath expression. as filterData="cc://value &gt; 500 . But still it is showing the the same exception.

Comment: So the code in your sample is not the code which is causing you the error? So how are we supposed to help you if you can't even be bothered to post the code which is causing the error?

Comment: Really sorry for the miss understanding! 'Original' means i want to say that when i had written that code first I was not using 'Quantity' as property but as i said i though it might be a serialization error that's why i started using it. The code which  i have posted is real one which i am currently using it. Please do not miss understand it. sorry for ur inconvenience . Pushkar

Answer (score 0):

Hey The problem is in the line

```
filter name="All" filterType="XPath" filterData="cc://value1 &gt; 500 "
```

It should be

```
<filter name="All" filterType="XPath" filterData="//cc:value1 &gt; 500 " />
```

observe cc:// in ur code.

This will solve ur problem